# Update objects in a list concurrently

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

I am wondering whether it is possible to update objects in list concurrently. For example if i have a list of games (let's say i have thousands of these) with status "STARTED". based on the time a game started i could choose to change the status to "END" if it passes after a period of time, for example 30 seconds.

Here's my example using spring

```
class Game{
  Date startTime;
  String status;

  //setters and getters
}

class MyUpdateService{

 private Dao dao;

 public void updateActiveGames(){
   List<Games> games = dao.getActiveGames();

   for(Game g : games){
       if(//current time >= 30 secs after startTeime){
          g.setStatus("ENDED");
          dao.update(g);
       }
   }

 }

}
```

Now if the list has thousands of game objects, it is possible that the games at the end of the list are way passed the 30 seconds if i use a for loop so i want it to update them concurrently instead.

Comment: What JDK version you are usng here? And what kind of framework, spring?

Comment: You could go for spring batch, it is good for mass updates/inserts. I am not sure if it's safe with dao, but JDK8 has pararell streams, that could be good for updating objects, but without cals to external objects, like dao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would perform a bulk update in your DAO.
For example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND,-30);
dao.updateStatusWithStartTime(cal.getTime(),"ENDED");
```

Barry